# confused addition operator logic

Tags: javascript, function

Why does the variable **counter** keep increasing when it re-initializes itself back to 0 in the self-invoking function?

```
 var add = (function () {
     var counter = 0;
     return function () {
        return counter += 1;
     }
 })();

 add();
 add();
 add();

 // the counter is still 3 when this line of code exists
 // var counter = 0;
```

So when add() function gets invoked, a function runs first with initializing counter = 0 and returning another function that returns the incremental value of **counter**. Why is this the case when there's **var counter = 0;** ?

source: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

**edit: November 16th, 2017**

Okay so it makes a lot more sense now from both of the answers given on this page. For extra clarification, I will add my own reasoning to give it a better visualization of why this happens.

```
 //first call of add()
 (function(){ // a self-invoking function
    var counter = 0; // executes once with the self-invoking function
    return function() { return counter += 1; } //explained below
 });

 //since the self-invoke function ran already, add() will begin to run the returned function:
 add = function() { return counter += 1; };
 add(); ----> counter += 1; -----> add.counter = 1;
 //counter acts like this.counter, so it's a part of add()
 //counter is now at 1

 //second call of add();
 //add has now officially been **transformed** to the new function:
 add = function() {
    return counter += 1;
 };
 //while add.counter still **exists** and remains in the self-invoke 
 //function. Do we call this **limbo variable** ? Don't know.
 //add.counter is at 2

 //third call of add();
 function() {
   return counter += 1;
 }
 //add.counter is at 3!
```

Comment: Take a look at the "Example Explained" of your source.

Comment: but aren't we re-initializing it again back to 0 after adding?

Comment: @RolandStarke I did but I'm still stuck at this comment **"The self-invoking function only runs once"**, Why does the self-invoking function run **once** when add() gets called **3 times** for counter to become the value of 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that "var add" assigned a self invoking function **that returns a function.**
Whatever above the return statement is the self invoking function closure. Which means that it is available to the returned function.
So it is in fact only initialized once. And then the return function, which is what the variable "add" now contains, increments the counter whenever it is invoked.

Comment: Wow really?!?! I never knew it would work like that. Wow wow. I will edit my original question with an explained answer for future references. Thanks for the extra clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Because the variable `add` contains the result of the self invoking function. So the value of `add` is this:

```
function () {
    return counter += 1;
}
```

The counter variable is only initialized before this function is set to the `add` variable.

Comment: It feels so strange but I get it now. It's like **counter** is stuck in limbo somewhere but it's still there! hah. Thanks!